# Convert character to number, like +00005 to 5

Tags: sql, casting, type-conversion, amazon-redshift, numeric

We have the fixed format data and it has the number with plus/minus sign, like +00005 or -00005.
We'd like to convert it to number but Redshift seems not to allow implicit conversion.

So, I temporarily use `to_number(replace(<numbercolumn>, '+', ''),'99999')`
But I guess there should be more better solutions.

Anyone know more smart way, your advice would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use cast(colname as datatype):

```
select cast('-00005' as int)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your prompt answer !! (I was overthinking it :)